# Select2 with Drag and Drop Sorting

Tags: jquery-select2

Select2 (v3.5.1) have a Drag&Drop function but only für "input" fields. I need a value/text combination, so only a selectbox is for me the right choice.

I found a (part) solution for my problem here: http://joevanderjagt.com/better-multiple-select-with-sorting/

But, its have a bug. Its working fine with sorting tags, but not, if user only add tags without sorting.
I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8v3su36/

```
<select id="test" size="1" multiple="multiple" style="width:400px">
    <option value="a">AAA</option>
    <option value="b">BBB</option>
    <option value="c">CCC</option>    
</select>

(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        select2_sortable: function(){
            var select = $(this);
            $(select).select2();
            var ul = $(select).prev('.select2-container').first('ul');
            ul.sortable({
                placeholder : 'ui-state-highlight',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                items       : 'li:not(.select2-search-field)',
                tolerance   : 'pointer',
                stop: function() {
                    $($(ul).find('.select2-search-choice').get().reverse()).each(function() {
                        var id = $(this).data('select2Data').id;
                        var option = select.find('option[value="' + id + '"]')[0];
                        $(select).prepend(option);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#test').select2_sortable();
}(jQuery));
```

Add first "CCC" and now "BBB" and press debug button. You will see order
"AAA, BBB, CCC" but must be "CCC,BBB,AAA"

Now use drag&drop the move "BBB" as first entry. click again debug button and see correct order "BBB,CCC,AAA".

Can anybody help here? I wish that add a entry is sorting the option in select too. :)

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**: http://jsfiddle.net/s8v3su36/4/

Answer (score 1):

With vue.js - please consider using this component (compact on the page, comfortable to use even with long list of options):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-libs-multi-select-with-order
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your magic debug button just outputs the `<select>` children, which remain the same when the page first loads or you add options to the select2 `div`.

Only after you stop the drag, the `stop` function gets executed and rearranges the `<option>` tags.

Try to reorder your `<select>` on the `add` event too.

Comment: Yes, I know that only after stop event the option is rearranges. But what is here the best way to make it for selecting?

Answer (score 0):

Added:

```
$(select).on("change", function(e)
{
    if (e.added)
    {
        var select = $(this);
        var ul = $(select).prev('.select2-container').first('ul');
        $($(ul).find('.select2-search-choice').get().reverse()).each(function() {
            var id = $(this).data('select2Data').id;
            var option = select.find('option[value="' + id + '"]')[0];
            $(select).prepend(option);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code from ([@ambroiseRabier](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3004#issuecomment-240434765)).
My code is more clean, don't use $(ul).find to find selected options. Instead it uses the passed ui element, to find selected options and original select element that needs to be updated. This version works properly if you have more Select2 instances in the web page.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.select2Sortable = function () {
    this.next().children().children().children().sortable({
        containment: 'parent', stop: function (event, ui) {
            var originalSelectElement = ui.item.parent().parent().parent().parent().prev();
            ui.item.parent().children('[title]').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                var originalOptionElem = $(originalSelectElement).children('[value="' + title + '"]');
                originalOptionElem.detach();
                $(originalSelectElement).append(originalOptionElem)
            });
            $(originalSelectElement).change();
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified it; you can try using this code. I hope it works:

```
var selectable = $('#id').select2();

selectable.next().children().children().children().sortable({
    containment: 'parent', stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.parent().children('[title]').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            var original = $( 'option:contains(' + title + ')', selectable ).first();
            original.detach();
            selectable.append(original)
        });
        selectable.change();
    }
});
```